# OpenVZ Debian 9.1 with only systemd, sshd and bash running: 80+ MByte of memory unavailable. Normal?

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I recently dist-upgraded my OpenVZ VPS to Debian 9.1 and am now running into constant memory problems. There are only 128 MByte + 64 Mbyte of swap available, so I'm aware that it would be a tight situation in any case. But even with everything stopped that I could bring myself to deactivate, I only have 50 MByte of memory available, sometimes even less. Sample output of `free`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         131072       23684       49056        6700       58332       49509
Swap:         65536        2140       63396
```

Sample output of `ps axu`:

```
root         1  0.0  2.5 208600  3300 ?        Ss   Oct10   2:32 init -z       
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:00 [kthreadd/27403]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct10   0:02 [khelper/27403]
root        62  0.0  0.1  43108   144 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       120  0.0  0.9  46460  1284 ?        Ss   Oct10   1:24 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+   127  0.0  0.6  45060   792 ?        Ss   Oct10   3:21 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
root       318  0.0  0.0  12612     8 tty1     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep
root       319  0.0  0.0  12612     8 tty2     Ss+  Oct10   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty2 l
root       362  0.0  0.0  20168     8 ?        Ss   Oct10   0:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /ru
root      5275  0.1  2.0  59976  2724 ?        Ss   03:33   0:02 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root      8428  0.0  0.3  69888   520 ?        Ss   Oct15   0:18 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     14452  0.0  3.3  99256  4412 ?        Ss   04:01   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root     14456  0.0  2.4  56248  3236 ?        Ss   04:01   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
root     14457  0.0  0.9 236184  1180 ?        S    04:01   0:00 (sd-
root     14467  0.0  1.9  20184  2588 pts/0    Ss   04:01   0:00 -bash
root     16404  0.0  2.9  99136  3916 ?        Ss   04:08   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd     16405  0.0  1.2  69888  1608 ?        S    04:08   0:00 sshd: root [net]
root     16406  0.0  1.3  38184  1776 pts/0    R+   04:08   0:00 ps axu
```

(The `(sd-` is sd-pam, no idea why ps cuts it off like that.)

Are these numbers to be expected? And if not, can you tell what's going wrong or tell me what additional information to supply? I've always had trouble understanding the finer points of memory handling in Linux, so I'm kinda at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Cache/buffer and shared will take some memory, when application need memory it will get free ones first and then it will release cache/buffer memory

Comment: `man free`: "available - Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache or free fields,  this  field takes into account page cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)"

So no, that's not it. I no longer have that system, though, so hard to run differentials now.